# How to get Access Token after login with IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4, aspnetboilerplate

I want to store Access Token after login to memory cache so that I can validate token on every request and deactivate it when user logout (currently the token is not removed after logout).
I have searched and tried some solution but they didn't work.
Could anyone give me some advices to get token and how to validate it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [IdentityModel.AspNetCore](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/web.html) together with a SessionStore in AddCookies, just like this picture below shows:

The SessionStore in AddCookies can then cache the tokens in memory, instead of as by default storing the tokens inside the cookies.

As an alternative you can add an EventHandler to AddCookies that triggers each time a request arrives and there lookup if a token should be disabled.

The alternative is to use [Reference tokens](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/tokens/reference/) with IdentityServer, then the API's receiving the tokens must ask IdentityServer on each request if the token is valid or not.

I did write a blog post, talking more about the purpose of the session store and how it can
improve security at:
[Improving ASP.NET Core Security By Putting Your Cookies On A Diet](https://nestenius.se/2024/01/22/improving-asp-net-core-security-by-putting-your-cookies-on-a-diet/)